# IE9 Browser modes and conditional comments

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, conditional-statements, html5boilerplate

I'm using HTML Boilerplate document header which adds various classes to the   tag for version of IE. When using IE9 (pressing F12) and changing the Browser Mode, I seem to remember this would always show the relevant browser (IE8/IE7 or IE7 when in Compatibility mode), however, this now doesn't seem to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- [if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!-- [if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!-- [if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!-- [if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

The site can be seen at http://rangeessentials.petersenuploads.co.uk/

It also doesn't seem to work using my IE7 Virtual Machine. What have I missed as I always get the final  tag with no IE classes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having multiple `<html>` begin tags, which is probably illegal anyways, you should have multiple style sheets and then the relevant styles applied accordingly in those style sheets:

```
<!-- [if lt IE 7]><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Styles_IE-7.css" /><![endif]-->
<!-- [if IE 7]><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Styles_IE7.css" /><![endif]-->
<!-- [if IE 8]><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Styles_IE8.css" /><![endif]-->
<!-- [if gt IE 8]><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Styles_IE8-.css" /><![endif]-->
```

But even in your code, there is a `<!-->` and `<!--` in your last conditional comment - that could be the issue, as well.

Comment: It should be ok. Certainly most of the current boilerplate type solutions are using it http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/, http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of it though. How is having multiple html begin tags better than having multiple style sheets?

Comment: No, only one <html> tag gets rendered, but it allows you to do things like .lt-ie7 ul li {display: inline; zoom:1} where you might have used display: inline-block; Basically is a neater way to target IE browsers without using hacks. Take a look at http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: Oh I understand that. But instead of rendering one of many <html> tags, isn't it easier to render one of many <link> tags for appropriate style sheets, like in my answer? Then instead of `.lt-ie7 ul li { ... }`, you just have `ul li { ... }` in Styles_IE-7.css or w/e.

Comment: In the past, yes, but this is aimed for at responsive sites where you load a stylesheet based on screensizes (media queries). Doing it that way, you get a set of styles for each IE for each screen size. This way, you can just combine all of your IE fixes into one stylesheet (also better for download speed as you've not got lots of files)

Comment: Sure, but you're only winning a little: from 2 stylesheets to 1. For a given resolution, if you use the <link> approach, you have 1 stylesheet for all browsers and 1 for the specified IE version loaded by the client; with <html> tag, you have 1 stylesheet with all your IE fixes right in it. While it is beneficial performance wise, I would argue that it's not ideal from readability and maintainability perspectives and it would be better to use a stylesheet "combiner" and "compresser" to improve performance.